# Take maximum rainfall value for each season over a time period (xarray)

Tags: python, group-by, dataset, netcdf4, python-xarray

I'm trying to find the maximum rainfall value for each season `(DJF, MAM, JJA, SON)` over a 10 year period. I am using netcdf data and xarray to try and do this. The data consists of rainfall (recorded every 3 hours), lat, and lon data. Right now I have the following code:

```
ds.groupby('time.season).max('time')
```

However, when I do it this way the output has a shape of `(4,145,192)` indicating that it's taking the maximum value for each season over the entire period. I would like the maximum for each individual season every year. In other words, output should have something with a shape like `(40,145,192)` (4 values for each year x 10 years)

I've looked into trying to do this with `DataSet.resample` as well using `time=3M` as the frequency, but then it doesn't split the months up correctly. If I have to I can alter the dataset, so it starts in the correct place, but I was hoping there would be an easier way considering there's already a function to group it correctly.

Thanks and let me know if you need anymore details!

Comment: Add a column for the year and do `ds.groupby(by=['time.season', 'year']).max()`

Comment: Thank you! I will try doing this. (New to using xarray and pandas so still learning how to do anything beyond the basics)

Answer (score 2):

Resample is going to be the easiest tool for this job. You are close with the time frequency but you probably want to use the quarterly frequency with an offset:

```
ds.resample(time='QS-Mar').max('time')
```

These offsets can be further configured as described in the Pandas documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases

Comment: So if I'm understanding this correctly, by adding the `QS-Mar` it's shifting each quarter back a month, starting with the first quarter (January-March becomes December-February)?

Comment: Right. I meant to say, you can set the starting month to anything you like. I choose `Mar` but you could also use `Dec` and get the same effect.