# Efficient workaround to group by multiple time coordinates in xarray

Tags: python, pandas, performance, pandas-groupby, python-xarray

I'm currently working with CESM Large Ensemble data on the cloud (ala https://medium.com/pangeo/cesm-lens-on-aws-4e2a996397a1) using xarray and Dask and am trying to plot the trends in extreme precipitation in each season over the historical period (Dec-Jan-Feb and Jun-Jul-Aug specifically).

Eg. If one had a daily time-series data split into months like:

```
1920: J,F,M,A,M,J,J,A,S,O,N,D
1921: J,F,M,A,M,J,J,A,S,O,N,D
...
```

My aim is to group together the JJA days in each year and then take the maximum value within that group of days for each year. Ditto for DJF, however here you have to be careful because DJF is a `year-skipping` season; the most natural way to define it is `1921's DJF = 1920 D + 1921 JF`.

Using iris this would be simple (though quite inefficient), as you could just add auxiliary time-coordinates for `season` and `season_year` and then aggregate/groupby those two coordinates and take a maximum, this would give you a (year, lat, lon) output where each year contains the maximum of the precipitation field in the chosen season (eg. maximum DJF precip in 1921 in each lat,lon pixel).

However in xarray this operation is not as natural because you can't natively groupby multiple coordinates, see https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/324 for further info on this. However, in this github issue someone suggests a simple, nested workaround to the problem using xarray's `.apply()` functionality:

```
def nested_groupby_apply(dataarray, groupby, apply_fn):
    if len(groupby) == 1:
        return dataarray.groupby(groupby[0]).apply(apply_fn)
    else:
        return dataarray.groupby(groupby[0]).apply(nested_groupby_apply, groupby = groupby[1:], apply_fn = apply_fn)
```

**I'd be quite keen to try and use this workaround myself, but I have two main questions beforehand:**

1) I can't seem to work out how to groupby coordinates such that I don't take the maximum of DJF in the same year?

Eg. If one simply applies the function like (for a suitable xr_max() function):

```
outp     = nested_groupby_apply(daily_prect, ['time.season', 'time.year'], xr_max)

outp_djf = outp.sel(season='DJF')
```

Then you effectively define `1921's DJF` as `1921 D + 1921 JF`, which isn't actually what you want to look at! This is because the 'time.year' grouping doesn't account for the `year-skipping` behaviour of seasons like DJF. I'm not sure how to workaround this?

2) This nested groupby function is **incredibly slow!** As such, I was wondering if anyone in the community had found a more efficient solution to this problem, with similar functionality?

Thanks ahead of time for your help, all! Let me know if anything needs clarifying.

**EDIT: Since posting this, I've discovered there already is a workaround for this in the specific case of taking DJF/JJA means each year ([Take maximum rainfall value for each season over a time period (xarray)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49639101/take-maximum-rainfall-value-for-each-season-over-a-time-period-xarray?rq=1)), however I'm keeping this question open because the general problem of an efficient workaround for multi-coord grouping is still unsolved.**